# PHP: Testing whether three variables are equal

Tags: php, variables, equality

I've never come across this before, but how would you test whether three variables are the same? The following, obviously doesn't work but I can't think of an elegant (and correct) way to write the following:

`if ($select_above_average === $select_average === $select_below_average) { }`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
if ((a == b) && (b == c)) {
   ... they're all equal ...
}
```

by the [transitive relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation)

Comment: Use `===`, not `==`.  PHP's loose equality is not transitive!

Comment: It should be noted that the parentheses around each comparison are *not* required.

Comment: This can be continued like this `(a === b && b === c && c === d && d === e)` etc.. to check if multiple variables are all equal.

Comment: -1, `==` is _not_ transitive in PHP, if you use values `$a='0'; $b=0; $c='0_php_fail';`, `($a == $b) && ($b == $c)` evaluates to true, while  `$a == $c` evaluates to false

Comment: I think saying they are entirely unrequired is rather an opinion than a fact. First off, the pharentheses make the statement much more readable, second off, removing them can lead to unexpected behaviour when using some language constructs. note that, for example, `include` uses everything after it as one single parameter while `(include ...) ...` would behave differently. sorry if this may be a bad example for you, but it's true for many php-language-"constructs". not only for `include`.

Answer (score 29):

```
$values = array($select_above_average, $select_average, $select_below_average);

if(count(array_unique($values)) === 1) {
    // do stuff if all elements are the same
}
```

Would be another way to do it.

Comment: Yowza, talk about driving 500 miles to get a Slurpee at the 7-11 instead walking down to the block to the 7-11 there.

Comment: :) That's why I said another way. Cause the answer wal already given :). I had to laugh though bout your comment.

Comment: This solution worked for my problem, which was how to check for a min/max number of equal values in a set (say, less than 3 out of 5 given values equal) with a single line. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

```
if ($select_above_average === $select_average
    && $select_average === $select_below_average) { }
```

Answer (score 6):

you already have your answer by Adam but a good way to remember how to do this correctly is to remember for a single validation you should be wrapping in `()` braces, if your only doing one single check then you already have the braces provided by the if **(**  **)** statement.

Example:

if **(** *a === b* **)**

and if your doing multiple then

if(  **(** *a === b* **)** && **(** *c === d* **)** )

Sop if you remember that every set of braces is a validation check, you can have login like this:

if(  **((** *a === b* **)** || **(** *c === d* **))** && **(** *e === f* **)** )

if statements and many other logical operations work on hierarchy so that the amount of individual checks within a check has an effect on he parent check.

taking the third example above if `a === b` or `c === d` fails then `e === f` will never be checked as the ab,cd is wrapped in braces so that is returned and checked.

Hope this helps you a little more.

Comment: This was a useful and helpful example. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I had a unique situation in which I needed to see if the amount of items in three arrays was the same much like this scenario.

This is what I came up with:

(Assume that fields, operators and values are all arrays)

```
$allfieldscount = array(count($fields), count($operators), count($values)); //store an array of the count of all the arrays.

$same = array_count_values($allfieldscount);//returns an array by values in the array.  We are looking to see only 1 item in the array with a value of 3.

if(count($same) != 1){
    //Then it's not the same
}else{
   //Then it's the same
}
```

This tactic counts the fields in the different arrays and by using array_count_values if they are all the same then the count of the array it returns will be '1', if it's anything else then it's not the same.  Look up array_count_values on php.net to understand more what its doing.