# Checking if 4 Values are the Same

Tags: php, do-while

I'm looking for the simplest way to check if 4 (or more) randomly generated values are the same.  I have a do-while loop here...

```
do {
    $var_a = mt_rand(1, 2);
    $var_b = mt_rand(1, 2);
    $var_c = mt_rand(1, 2);
    $var_d = mt_rand(1, 2);
} while ($var_a == $var_b == $var_c == $var_d);
```

PHP doesn't like the `$var_a == $var_b == $var_c == $var_d` part though.  I know I could individually check each combination of $var_a, $var_b, etc. to see if they're equal, but is there a cleaner way of doing this?

**Edit:** Most of the answers/comments given are fine for this instance.  I'm wondering about times where you could be checking, say... 20 different variables.  In that case, it would be tedious to check all of the numerous combinations.  Thanks to the people who have responded about this specific situation though.

Comment: use or: ($var1 == $var2 or $var1 == $var3) etc;

Comment: possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702852/php-testing-whether-three-variables-are-equal][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702852/php-testing-whether-three-variables-are-equal

Comment: You can only get 2 unique values with `mt_rand(1, 2)`

Comment: how about creating 4 non identical values in the first place?

Comment: for just all 1's ore all 2's there are a number of alternative approaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
do {
    $var_a = mt_rand(1, 2);
    $var_b = mt_rand(1, 2);
    $var_c = mt_rand(1, 2);
    $var_d = mt_rand(1, 2);
} while (($var_a == $var_b)&&($var_a == $var_c)&&($var_a == $var_d));
```

Comment: Works well for this specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
function checkifequal () {
  if (func_num_args() <= 1)
    return true;
  else
    for ($i = 1; $i < func_num_args(); $i++)
      if (func_get_arg[0] != func_get_arg[$i])
        return false;
  return true;
}

do {
    $var_a = mt_rand(1, 2);
    $var_b = mt_rand(1, 2);
    $var_c = mt_rand(1, 2);
    $var_d = mt_rand(1, 2);
} while (!checkifequal($var_a, $var_b, $var_c, $var_d));
```

Didn't check for errors, but it should work with a variable amount of parameters.

Comment: Seems like it would be useful for larger number of variables.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try using the AND operator

```
while ($var_a == $var_b && $var_b == $var_c &&  $var_c == $var_d && $var_d == $var_a);
```

hope that's gonna work

Regards

Shiva

Answer (score 0):

Can't get much more readable than:

```
$var_a == $var_b && $var_a == $var_c && $var_a == $var_d
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array

```
<?php
do {
    $var = array();
    $var[] = mt_rand(1, 4);
    $var[] = mt_rand(1, 4);
    $var[] = mt_rand(1, 4);
    $var[] = mt_rand(1, 4);
} while (count(array_unique($var)) != 4);
var_dump($var);
```

http://codepad.org/0vWi3jy5

Note I changed `mt_rand(1, 2)` to `mt_rand(1, 4)` to allow for more than 2 unique values.

Comment: I need the variables as "$var_a", "$var_b", etc. though.

Comment: then load them out of the array once you're done. Look at `list`.